# How does ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier relate to the Microsoft GraphApi UserID

Tags: asp.net-core, microsoft-graph-api

I'm using User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier) to retrieve the user Id of the current logged in user. The resulting seems to be a random string.

If I look up a user in Azure AD the ID there looks like a guid. And if lookup a user in the Graph Api the Id is also a Guid. Is there some way to relate the two properties?

Or is the .net core current user not related to the logged in Azure Ad user?

Comment: Great question...I have the same one...

Comment: Seems there's no way to use the NameIdentifier for this purpose. Cf. https://stackoverflow.com/a/61667510/6996150