# Azure Ad convert sub/NameIdentifier to objectidentifier

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I have an application that has stored the openid subject/NameIdentifier to identify users. Now a featurerequest was made that requires retrieving a user from the Microsoft Graph api while the user isn't logged in. Which requires the objectidentifier to find the user. Is there someway to convert the nameidentifier to the objectidentifier without requiring the users to login. 
Can I retrieve the nameidentifier with the graph Api

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use `Nameidentifier` to fetch the user information from the Tenant level using GarphApi which is unique only to the application level.

The `ID/UPN` is the unique across the Tenant which can be used to fetch user information.

The converstion of `Sub/Nameidentifier` to `oid/UPN` is not possible as these two are different unique id generated by azure.

In this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/id-tokens#payload-claims) you can find more information about `sub/oid` here